# Storing hundres of millions data segments

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, cloud, bigdata, database

A system I'm working on needs to store streams of strings sent by devices 24/7.
For example, a device with id 'ID', sends a different string every 10 seconds.
So, I need to store the following data item:

```
('ID', t, t+10, somestring)
```

We're talking about thousands of devices, meaning, hundreds of millions data sets.

The most important query is:

```
Query(id, start, end) ==> list of strings
```

How would you recommend storing the data?
Which database would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Cassandra this is pretty straight forward.

```
CREATE TABLE device_strings (
  id text,
  year_month_day text,
  start timestamp,
  end timestamp,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id, year_month_day), start, end)
);
```

This means that each ID/day will have a partition (you cant let them grow unbounded). This means in your query you have to potentially read multiple times if start/end span across a day.

Answer (score 0):

This is timeSeries data and Cassandra might be a good fit for TimeSeries kind of data. Store data by id, start(descending), end (descending) as primary key in Cassandra. Your writes and reads will be fast and can be linearly scaled for performance. 
Note: Cassandra limits the number for values for partition to 2Billion, if you do not want to set TTL for the old data, you should think about adding another key to the partition to limit the value. This would also give you ability to spread the data across the cluster should there be only few ID which are constantly sending data.